# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

//[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Seflu.png)

```
<div  v-for='(place) in query.visitPlaces' :key="place.name">

            <div class="column is-4 is-narrow">
            <b-field label="Nights">
            <b-input type="text" v-model="place.nights" placeholder="e.g. Bandra" required></b-input>
            </b-field>
            </div>

         <div class="card hotel-card" v-for='(hotel, index) in place.hotels' :key="hotel.name">
<header class="card-header">
      <b-tooltip label="Delete Hotel" position="is-left">
     <a  class="card-header-icon" aria-label="Delete Hotel" @click="removeHotel(index)">
                            <span class="icon">
                               <i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
                            </span>
                         </a> 
                      </b-tooltip> 
                 </header>
               </div> </div>
```

// Javascript

```
 removeHotel(index) {
          console.log(index);
          this.query.hotels.splice(index, 1);
          //this.priceList = {};
        },
```

> Uncaught Type Error: Cannot read property 'splice' of undefined.

This error continues to occur. Please help me.

Comment: this means that this.qury.hotels is undefined. So there is an issue in your code somewhere that this.qury.hotels is not set.

Comment: could you please show us your data structure of query.hotels?

Answer (score 0):

It mean `this.query.hotels` is undefined. So add if condition like below

```
removeHotel(index) {
  console.log(index);
  if(this.query.hotels && this.query.hotels.length > 0) {
    this.query.hotels.splice(index, 1);
   }
  //this.priceList = {};
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You've expected `this.query.hotels` to be an array but you didn't define it as one at the time the function was called.

You can test if a variable is an Array by using the static [`.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) method

```
function removeHotel(index) {
    if(Array.isArray(this.query.hotels) && this.query.hotels.length > 0) {
        this.query.hotels.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```